# Android: Toggle button doesnt update

Tags: java, android, button, auto-update, ui-thread

I'm having some problems trying to set togglebutton (LeftLightButton) state and text after receiving value 1 at novo.charAt(0) for example. The main idea is, i click the button, it makes webview.loadUrl, and if the page changes to what i expected the toggle button state should be on, if not, it must stay off and vice versa. The way it is now, doesnt change the text neither state in case the site didnt update to the value that i was expecting.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
private ToggleButton LeftLightButton;
private Thread webviewthread;
private String baseURL;

private boolean LeftLightButtonState;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Context context = this;
    baseURL = "http://192.168.1.4/i.php";

    LeftLightButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                synchronized(this) {
                    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.addJavascriptInterface(context, "HTMLOUT");

                    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
                        }
                    });

                    webView.loadUrl(baseURL);
                }
            }
        });

    showToast("Getting current status...");

}

public void notify(final boolean state, final ToggleButton buttonName) {

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait(1000);
                    final ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
                    if (!state && button.isChecked()) {
                        showToast("Couldnt turn OFF");
                        // UI
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                button.setChecked(false);
                                button.setTextOff("OFF");
                            }
                        });
                        // end of UI

                    }
                    if (state && !button.isChecked()) {
                        showToast("Couldnt turn ON");
                        // UI
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                button.setChecked(true);
                                button.setTextOn("ON");
                            }
                        });
                        // end of UI
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }


        }
    };
    thread.start();

}

public void showToast(final String toast)
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {

    final int id = arg0.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.toggleButton1:
        if (LeftLightButtonState == true) {
            webView.loadUrl(baseURL+"?L=0");
            notify(false, LeftLightButton);
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl(baseURL+"?L=1");
            notify(true, LeftLightButton);
        }
        break;
    // even more buttons here
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void processHTML(String html) { // <html> <body> 1 0 0 0 </body> </html>
    LeftLightButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    String novo = android.text.Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
    System.out.println("RECEIVED: "+novo);

    if (novo != null) {
        if (novo.charAt(0) == '0') {
            LeftLightButtonState = false;       
            LeftLightButton.setTextOff("OFF");
            LeftLightButton.setChecked(false);

        }
        if (novo.charAt(0) == '1') {
            LeftLightButtonState = true;
            LeftLightButton.setTextOn("ON");
            LeftLightButton.setChecked(true);

        }
        System.out.println("CHEGUEI");
    }


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different string in the xml files itself. Then based on the state appropriate text will be displayed. You can call setChecked(true/false) to select or unselect the Toggle Button.. It is working fine in my project.

```
    android:textOff="@string/dontshowtraffic"
    android:textOn="@string/showtraffic"
```